# Does a pointwisely convergent sequence of quadratic functions pointwisely converges to a quadratic one?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, convergence-divergence, matrix-calculus

Let $\{f_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of functions $f_j:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ quadratically parameterized as $f_j(x) = x^T P_j x$ for a symmetric matrix $P_j \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Let $f_j$ pointwisely converges to a function $f$.

Then, *can we say that $f$ is also quadratic so that $f(x) = x^T P x$ for some symmetric $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$?*

---

I was particularly interested in the case: $f_j$ is monotonically increasing and bounded by a quadratic function $g(x) = x^T Q x$:
\begin{equation}
f_1(x) \leq \cdots \leq f_j(x) \leq f_{j+1}(x) \leq \cdots \leq g(x) < \infty \;\;\, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n.
\end{equation}
In that case, by MCT, $f_j \to f$ pointwisely for some $f$, and we also have $P_j \to P$ for some symmetric $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, by MCT again, due to 
\begin{equation}
   P_1 \leq \cdots \leq P_j \leq P_{j+1} \leq \cdots \leq Q.
\end{equation}
In this case, $f(x) = x^T P x$ is true since $x^T P_j x \to x^T P x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Moreover, if $f(x) = x^T P x$ is true, then it is trivially continuous, so that the convergence is uniform on any compact $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ by Dini's theorem.

*However, I can't see whether $f(x) = x^T P x$ is true or not in general case without monotonicity.*

Comment: Each $f_j$ is homogeneous of degree $2$, hence the pointwise limit is also homogeneous of degree $2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer There are plenty of functions homogeneous of degree 2 that don't take that form.

Comment: @zhw. Dang, I forgot the differentiability requirement.

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer, @zhw Do you know some reference about the convergence of homogeneous functions? Now, I know what the homogeneous function of degree $n$ means from Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function), but there's nothing about the convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a polarization identity which gives us
 $$B_j(x,y)=x^T P_j y = \frac{1}{2}\left(f_j(x+y)-f_j(x-y)\right)$$
This determines a unique symmetric bilinear form in $x,y$.
The hypothesis is that $f_j$ converges pontwise so from the above identity:
$$ B(x,y) = \lim_{j\rightarrow \infty} B_j(x,y)$$
exists for all $x,y$. One checks it is bilinear in $x$ and $y$, so has the form $x^T P y$. One recovers then that $f(x)=\lim_j f_j(x)=B(x,x)=x^T P x$.

Comment: So, by the p.w. convergence $f_j \to f$, $B(x,y)$ is given by $B(x,y) = \frac{1}{2} (f(x+y) - f(x-y))$, isn't it?

Comment: Precisely. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

The result for $n=1$ is straightforward. Suppose we know the result for $\mathbb R^n,$ and that $Q_j(x,y)$ is a sequence of quadratics on $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ that converges pointwise on $\mathbb R^{n+1}.$ Here $x= (x_1,\dots, x_n).$ We can write

$$Q_j(x,y) = R_j(x) + a_jy + y(b_{j1}x_1 + \cdots +b_{jn}x_n) + c_jy^2.$$

Here $R_j$ is a quadratic on $\mathbb R^n,$ and the coefficients of $Q_j$ are those of $R_j$ along with the coefficients involving $y$ indicated above.

Looking at $(x,0),$ the induction hypothesis shows the all sequences of coefficients of $R_j(x)$ converge, hence $R_j(x)$ converges pointwise on $\mathbb R^n.$ Thus $Q_j-R_j$ converges pointwise on $\mathbb R^{n+1}.$ If we now look at the variables $(0,x_1,\dots, x_n,y),$ the induction hypotheses tells us all remaining coefficent sequences converge, except for $b_{j1}.$ But now this last coefficient sequence is forced to come along for the ride, and we have the result.

Comment: I don't know what the convergence of $b_j x + d_j x^2$ at 1 and 2 means.

Comment: We are looking along $(x,0),$ which yields a one variable quadratic, which we can look at for $x=1,2.$

Comment: @ zhw Oh, I see. You proved it for $\mathbb{R}^2$ case.

Comment: I edited my answer to give a proof for all $n.$

Comment: Good, but I cannot follow after "If we now look at the variables $(0,x_1,…,x_n,y)$...." Why all of the coefficient sequences converge EXCEPT for $b_{j1}$? How about the other sequences $(b_{j2},\cdots,b_{jn})$?

Comment: Because setting $x_1=0$ results in quadratics on $\mathbb R^n$ that converge pointwise there.

Comment: So, $(0,x_1,\cdots,x_n,y)$ means that $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n,y)$ with $x_1 = 0$?

Comment: Yes it does $\,\,$